# Converting a DWORD without CRT, implementing custom sprintf() function

Tags: c++, c, printf, msvcrt

Background:

My application ships without a CRT as it MUST be portable and small.

Problem:

When I run my application on a Virtual Machine for Windows XP, my `CreateProcess()` function fails, I need to display the `GetLastError()` `DWORD` in a `MessageBox()` without using any of the CRT,

How can I manually implement `sprintf()` function in my program to convert the `DWORD` type to a `char buffer` to display in the `MessageBox()` function to get the error type, so I can therefore fix the problem.

I have implemented my own `memset()` function like so

```
extern "C" void * __cdecl memset(void *, int, size_t);


#pragma function(memset)
void * __cdecl memset(void *pTarget, int value, size_t cbTarget) {
unsigned char *p = static_cast<unsigned char *>(pTarget);
while (cbTarget-- > 0) {
    *p++ = static_cast<unsigned char>(value);
}
return pTarget;
}
```

I am unsure of how to implement a custom `sprintf()` function

Thank you

Comment: Just link statically. The linker will copy the `memcpy` and `sprintf` implementation into your executable. You can't avoid having a version of those functions, so why not choose a well-tested one?

Comment: There are size constraints to my application, otherwise I would.

Comment: So? Your application will contain the bytes necessary for `memcpy` regardless where the linker took those bytes from.

Comment: Statically linking the CRT still brings in TONS of stuff you don't use, I guess LTCG is not that smart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If speed is not what you'd concern, you can use RtlMoveMemory and wsprintf supplied by kernel32.dll for memcpy(memmove) and sprintf (Not actually THAT slow, just cannot do link time optimization).

Comment: Thanks I completely forgot about this implementation in Win32

Answer (score 4):

wsprintf is available in Windows, event without a CRT. Just #include windows.h